# Why does Pattern.quote always return a quoted string?

Tags: java, regex, optimization, pattern-matching

Pattern.quote("pattern") returns `\Qpattern\E`. Is it really necessary to literalize a string if there is no meta character in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not necessary, but that's what the implementer chose to do, probably to simplify the implementation and because the cost of the unnecessary `\Q` and `\E` is rather small.

In my JDK, the only thing that `Pattern.quote()` cares about is whether there are already `\Q` and `\E` in the pattern. It doesn't look for any other special characters.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's just simpler and more efficient. Instead of doing a first pass to see if there are meta characters, and then a second pass to quote them, just assume that there are metacharacters, and always quote.